# Extract words from PDF and parse like a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to parse a PDF file like a table-layout. Consider below PDF file:

[image]

I am trying to do, so users can define column like layout for the PDF file, like so:

[image]

This is my code:

```py
areas = {}
areas[0] = (0, 0, 150, 792)
areas[1] = (150, 0, 350, 792)
areas[2] = (350, 0, 612, 792)

with pdfplumber.open(mypdf_file) as pdf:
     for i, area in enumerate(areas):
         area = areas[i]
         p0 = pdf.pages[0]
         p0 = p0.crop(area)
         words = p0.extract_words()
```

Below is the extracted output that `words =` contains:

```
[[{'bottom': Decimal('99.708'),
  'text': 'Page'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('99.708'),
  'text': '1,'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('99.708'),
  'text': 'col'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('99.708'),
  'text': '1.'
}]
[{'bottom': Decimal('128.988'),
  'text': 'Page'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('128.988'),
  'text': '1,'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('128.988'),
  'text': 'col'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('128.988'),
  'text': '2.'
}]
[{'bottom': Decimal('143.628'),
  'text': 'Page'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('143.628'),
  'text': '1,'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('143.628'),
  'text': 'col'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('143.628'),
  'text': '3'
}]
```

I am trying to figure out a way to parse this information, so it will represent my image above. Because I only have the bbox information (`bottom`), and not the actual line breaks. So if I parse the above data:

```py
for i, area in enumerate(areas):
   [....]
   cols[i + 1] = " ".join(map(itemgetter("text"), words))
```

I get the words (combined to lines) as:

```py
{1: 'Page 1, col 1.', 2: 'Page 1, col 2.', 3: 'Page 1, col 3'}
```

## Expected output

I am trying to parse it like a table, by using the `bottom` value to determine whether or not a word is on the same "line".

**However, I am not sure how to go about this?** Are we able to check each line/word against the next one, in the next column, to see if they are on the same line?

Output *something* like:

```
{
    "1": [{
        "row": "Page 1, col 1.",
        "row": "",
        "row": ""
    }],
    "2": [{
        "row": "",
        "row": "Page 1, col 2.",
        "row": ""
    }],
    "3": [{
        "row": "",
        "row": "",
        "row": "Page 1, col 3."
    }]
  }
```

Comment: Your PDF images don't seem to work, can you edit the post to add them so potential answerers can see what you are working with?

Comment: They're working here - maybe something with Imgur? Let me know if you still can't see them, and I'll try to upload again.